# Attempt to read property "view" on null, laravel reset email notificaiton

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication, laravel-mail, laravel-notification

When I try to send reset password notification, this error occurs

```
Attempt to read property "view" on null
```

this is the code line on which this error occurs

```
$this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
```

this is my code inside notification class
[image]

Comment: Please do not post code images, instead post your actual code into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need this method in User model:

```php
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token): void
{
    $this->notify(new ResetPassword($token, $this));
}
```

You must pass user with token

Comment: I tried this, still same error

Comment: Do you have all auth views?

Comment: yes I've auth views in resources/views/auth

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the `MailMessage` in `toMail` like so:

```php
return $this->buildMailMessage($this->resetUrl($notification));
```